# How to change the Password Char Style in a Web Application

Tags: web-applications, passwords

The Password in default in every text box will appear like `•••••••••` in the Textbox instead of, I want to make it to be changed like `*************` in a Web Application. 
Can any one suggest me how to change the Style of the Password Char.

Comment: Can the people give a reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering of controls is done by the browser. There is no general way of mandating this that works across all browsers. Notably WebKit has options for styling certain controls and how they appear to the user, but those are prefixed with `-webkit` which tells already where they won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this is not available in HTML.  Each browser is free to implement as it wants.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a javascript solution that overlays a new input which you fill with the amount of # characters you already typed.